# WMIC Error when I try to set a registry value

Tags: registry, command-line-interface, wmic

Whenever I try to use the SetStringValue function from WMIC,
(with a command line like this:
`wmic /NameSpace:\\root\default Class StdRegProv Call SetStringValue hDefKey=&H80000001 sSubKeyName="SOFTWARE\Cain" sValue="running" sValueName="SomeName"`), I get this error:

```
Invalid named parameter list.
Hint: <named param list> ::= <named param> | <named param> <named param list> where <named param> ::= <param name>=<param value>
'H80000001' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried everything that i could think of, but i couldn't figure this one out. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Anyway, I solved my problem. The thing is that I needed a "^" right before the "&" in hDefKey=&H...